# can't compute gop using kaldi

Tags: c++, bash, shell, kaldi

i am using this code to compute gop score using kaldi https://github.com/jimbozhang/kaldi-gop
it is building fine but when i run run.sh command it throws this error, basically it is saying the script can't find apply-cmvn and add-deltas, how do i solve this?? i am unable to find any advice on the internet. I am a noob in bash scripting so can't read script files effectively

**Log file:**
{**# compute-gmm-gop exp/eval_gop/tree exp/eval_gop/final.mdl data/lang/L.fst "ark,s,cs:apply-cmvn --utt2spk=ark:data/eval/split1/1/utt2spk scp:data/eval/split1/1/cmvn.scp scp:data/eval/split1/1/feats.scp ark:- | add-deltas ark:- ark:- |" "ark:utils/sym2int.pl --map-oov 221 -f 2- data/lang/words.txt data/eval/split1/1/text|" ark,t:exp/eval_gop/gop.1 # Started at Thu Feb 23 22:31:43 IST 2023 # compute-gmm-gop exp/eval_gop/tree exp/eval_gop/final.mdl data/lang/L.fst 'ark,s,cs:apply-cmvn --utt2spk=ark:data/eval/split1/1/utt2spk scp:data/eval/split1/1/cmvn.scp scp:data/eval/split1/1/feats.scp ark:- | add-deltas ark:- ark:- |' 'ark:utils/sym2int.pl --map-oov 221 -f 2- data/lang/words.txt data/eval/split1/1/text|' ark,t:exp/eval_gop/gop.1 sh: 1: apply-cmvn: not found sh: 1: add-deltas: not found sym2int.pl: replacing ORALS with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing P with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing H with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing D with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing (TW-) with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing YAHOO with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing (N-) with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing (AL-) with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing (YOU) with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing (MEAN) with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing MHM with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing (PLANES) with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing SCHOLARLY with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing (US-) with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing RACHEL with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing (C-) with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing (%HESITATION) with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing (WEE-) with 221 sym2int.pl: replacing CESSNA with 221 ** Replaced 19 instances of OOVs with 221 LOG (compute-gmm-gop[5.3]:main():gopbin/compute-gmm-gop.cc:68) Done. WARNING (compute-gmm-gop[5.3]:Close():kaldi-io.cc:512) Pipe apply-cmvn --utt2spk=ark:data/eval/split1/1/utt2spk scp:data/eval/split1/1/cmvn.scp scp:data/eval/split1/1/feats.scp ark:- | add-deltas ark:- ark:- | had nonzero return status 32512 ERROR (compute-gmm-gop[5.3]:~SequentialTableReaderArchiveImpl():util/kaldi-table-inl.h:678) TableReader: error detected closing archive 'apply-cmvn --utt2spk=ark:data/eval/split1/1/utt2spk scp:data/eval/split1/1/cmvn.scp scp:data/eval/split1/1/feats.scp ark:- | add-deltas ark:- ark:- |' [ Stack-Trace: ] kaldi::MessageLogger::HandleMessage(kaldi::LogMessageEnvelope const&, char const*) kaldi::MessageLogger::~MessageLogger() kaldi::SequentialTableReaderArchiveImplkaldi::KaldiObjectHolder<kaldi::Matrix<float > >::~SequentialTableReaderArchiveImpl() kaldi::SequentialTableReaderArchiveImplkaldi::KaldiObjectHolder<kaldi::Matrix<float > >::~SequentialTableReaderArchiveImpl() kaldi::SequentialTableReaderkaldi::KaldiObjectHolder<kaldi::Matrix<float > >::~SequentialTableReader() main __libc_start_main _start terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error' what(): # Accounting: time=1 threads=1 # Ended (code 134) at Thu Feb 23 22:31:44 IST 2023, elapsed time 1 seconds**
}

Comment: Wrap you log output using the "{}" option (equivalent to <PRE>).

Comment: It's not good practice here on StackOverflow to ask readers to goto external sites to understand the basic problem. Please edit your question to include the code in question so that readers can copy/paste into their local environment and see your problem. and yes, please use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: And you'll probably do better about such installation/usage questions by posting a issue at the git-hub site. Good luck.